# Swift Filter array containing array of Strings

Tags: ios, swift

I want to filter an array which contains an array of Strings.

My code is:

```
if(!(searchString?.isEmpty)!) {
    shouldShowSearchResults = true

    // Filter the data array and get only those countries that match the search text.
    filteredPlazaDictionary = plazaDictionary.filter({ (match) -> Bool in
        let matchText: NSString = match[1] as NSString
        return (matchText.range(of: searchString!, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive).location) != NSNotFound
    })
}
```

Here, `filteredPlazaDictionary[[String]]` and `plazaDictionary[[String]]` and I want to match every array[1] inside `plazaDictionary` with searchString. Help please.

Comment: What does `(!(searchString?.isEmpty)!)` do? It seems far too complicated.

Comment: checks if it is empy

Comment: OK, so what is going wrong with your code? What IS happening that you think is not right?

Comment: @thewarri0r9, and crashes everything if `searchString` happens to be `nil`

Comment: Yes, it would. You didn't mention that in the question :) just writing an answer...

Comment: `(foo?.bar)!` is nonsense, to check for non-nil and non-empty use `if let query = searchString, !query.isEmpty { ...` (no parentheses at all).

Comment: No it does not crash anything, I just don't get matching strings in filteredPlazaDictionary

Comment: If `plazaDictionary` is a `[[String]]`, then why is it called `plazaDictionary`? It's an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: sorry for that confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write this something like this I think...

```
// make it a function that takes everything it needs and returns a result array
func filteredCountryArray(countryArray: [[String]], searchString: String) -> [[String]] {
    guard !searchString.isEmpty else {
        // search string is blank so return entire array...
        return countryArray
    }

    // Filter the data array and get only those countries that match the search text.
    return countryArray.filter { match in
        // check array is long enough to get [1] out of it
        guard match.count >= 2 else {
            return false
        }

        let matchText = match[1]
        return matchText.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    }
}
```

`plazaDictionary` is a very odd name to give to an array. It is an array, not a dictionary.

What you should probably do here is create some data objects (structs, classes, enums, etc...) that hold the data in a better format than a nested array.

This should do what you want for now though.

**EDIT**

Having another think about it, I would also change the serachString and the array into input parameters...

Comment: Somthings strange is happening. I used your code : `filteredPlazaDictionary = self.filteredCountryArray(countryArray: plazaDictionary, searchString: searchString!)
       self.tollBothPlazaTableView.reloadData()` I am calling your function like this But when searchString isn't empty `cellForRowAt indexPath` doesn't get a called. In short tableView does not reload.

Comment: Cell for row is a completely unrelated function. Is the array being filtered properly?

Comment: Yes it is but if TableView is not reloading then its not helping.

Comment: @thewarri0r9 are you telling the table view to reload?

Comment: @thewarri0r9 look at your question. Nothing in there mentions anything about table view. This is a question about filtering an array. If you are having trouble elsewhere is nothing to do with this function.

Comment: Yeah there was a problem in my code therefore couldn't verify if your code was working. Thanks :)